# How to get a list of XAML resources defined in an Assembly?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to enumerate all XAML resources defined in an Assembly? I know how to retrieve a resource if you have it's Key available, but it isn't the case in my situation.

EDIT: 
Seems like I wasn't clear enough. I want to list XAML resources defined in an **external** Assembly that I know full path to.

Comment: you want all the resources whether they are defined in app/window/usercontrol/style?

Comment: I only need externally usable resources. I don't think you can use a resource defined in another assembly's UserControl/Window, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yeah, you can iterate resources through loops. For example, using `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var res in Application.Current.Resources)
{
     Console.WriteLine(res);
}
```

**Update:**

To get all `ResourceDictionary'ies` from external library, you should, at first, load the library, then get `ManifestResourceInfo`. Let me show an example:

```
string address = @"WpfCustomControlLibrary.dll";
List<Stream> bamlStreams = new List<Stream>();
Assembly skinAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(address);            
string[] resourceDictionaries = skinAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
foreach (string resourceName in resourceDictionaries)
{
   ManifestResourceInfo info = skinAssembly.GetManifestResourceInfo(resourceName);
   if (info.ResourceLocation != ResourceLocation.ContainedInAnotherAssembly)
   {
      Stream resourceStream = skinAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
      using (ResourceReader reader = new ResourceReader(resourceStream))
      {
         foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in reader)
         {
            //Here you can see all your ResourceDictionaries
            //entry is your ResourceDictionary from assembly
          }
      }
    }
}
```

You can see all your `ResourceDictionary`'s in `reader`. Please, see the above code.

I've tested this code and it works.

Comment: Sorry, seems like I wasn't clear in my question. I want to list resources from an external assembly that is not loaded in AppDomain currently.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it will list resources defined in XAML.

Comment: @ionoy please, see my updated answer. I've tested this code and it works.

Comment: Note that your files have to be marked as `Embedded Resource` so `GetManifestResourceNames()` finds it. For your first code example the file needs to be marked as `Resource`. Just to be clear..

Answer (score 10):

Try below code:

```
        ResourceDictionary dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
        dictionary.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfControlAssembly;Component/RD1.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
        foreach (var item in dictionary.Values)
        {
           //Operations
        }
```

Here `WpfControlAssembly` is name of your assembly.`Component` is fixed value and then `RD1.xaml` is a `Resource Dictionary`.

Below is the output:

**Resource Dictionary**

[image: Resource Dictionary]

**Code Output:**

[image: Output]

***PS: All `ResourceDictionary` Files should have `Build Action` as `'Resource'` or  `'Page'`.***

***Update :***

Finally I'm able to do this. Please use below method:

```
public ResourceDictionary GetResourceDictionary(string assemblyName)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);
        Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(asm.GetName().Name + ".g.resources");            
        using (ResourceReader reader = new ResourceReader(stream))
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in reader)
            {
                var readStream = entry.Value as Stream;
                Baml2006Reader bamlReader = new Baml2006Reader(readStream);
                var loadedObject = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(bamlReader);
                if (loadedObject is ResourceDictionary)
                {
                    return loadedObject as ResourceDictionary;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

***OUTPUT:***

[image: RD]

> ***Without any try-catch & expected `Exceptions` and I think in more WPF(instead of converting everything to `ResourceDictionary`) way.***

Comment: But what if I don't know the name of ResourceDictionary (RD1.xaml)? Is it possible to find names of all ResourceDictionaries in the assembly?

Comment: If you don't know the name of ResourceDictionaries, you can get that from AssamblyInfo but if you don't know the names how are you going to find the resources in them. I mean If you don't know the name of  .ResourceDictionaries but know the name of resources in them seems irony to me. I'm not sure what you want to achieve here.

Comment: @ionoy what all details do you have about this assembly?

Comment: Basically just full path and nothing more. Since I only want to enumerate resources, that should be enough. I think @StepUp suggested a good enough solution already. Gave you +1 anyway, thanks!

Comment: @ionoy ok. and were you able to retrieve the resources on the basis of a dictionary entry? converting DictionaryEntry to ResourceDictionary, how did you achieve that? were you able to differentiate between ResourceDictionary and other xaml files?

Comment: Still didn't get a chance to test this code out. But it seems to be doing what I need. I'll post an update when I get to actually try it.

Comment: @ionoy looking forward for that :) (cause I'm really skeptical about it.)

Comment: Just tested it. Basically, final solution is a combination of both answers. From @StepUp code I was able to get all resources, then filter them by `.baml` extensions, change it to `.xaml` and load using `Dictionary.Source`. This gives me all resources dictionaries (with resources it them) from all provided assemblies, which is what I needed.

Comment: @ionoy that probably the best idea. but do you wrote any logic to separate different type of .baml files. I mean all user control, resource distionary etc are all create baml files.

Comment: At the moment I resorted to setting `Source` property inside a `try/catch` block. It will fail if specified `Uri` is not a proper `ResourceDictionary`.

Comment: @ionoy this question was giving me headaches... finally I've done it(I think so)..fewwwwww..... please see my updated answer. :)... hopefully this will be end of it.

Comment: @ionoy is it's a better way?

Comment: Yes, this is good overall solution, thank you. You could enumerate resources with `GetManifestResourceNames`, so there is no need to hardcode a filename.

Comment: @ionoy it's not exactly hard coded cause it's the standard that assembly manifest file will have .g.resources suffix and never likely to change.It actually saves one more operation time.

Comment: Agreed. If it is consistent across XAML platforms, then it is a much more performant approach.