# How can you discover what XAML resources exist in an assembly?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, resources

If you don't know *a priori* what XAML resources exist in an assembly, how can you discover what they are? Assuming you have the assembly itself.

Example... [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2077528/3195477) listed out a set of theme styles that you can use. So for example you can include:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Classic;component/themes/Classic.xaml"/>
```

to use the 'classic' theme which resides in `PresentationFramework.Classic.dll`. But how could you discover that this assembly resource even existed in the first place?

I looked in object browser in Visual Studio, but it only shows ordinary classes. I looked at the DLL in ILSpy which shows:

[image]

but even from this its not really clear how to know what the usable resource path would be.

I'm not sure where else to look.

Comment: How about [How to get a list of XAML resources defined in an Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36639688/1136211)

Comment: @Clemens thanks, that's helpful. But I don't necessarily want to have to write code to do this (if possible). I didn't state it but I was hoping there was a simple tool-oriented way to do this. I'm now somewhat surprised that ILSpy didn't actually do what is in that question.

Comment: In case you're looking for a tool, StackOverflow is not the right place to ask. Just saying...