# Efficiently add all images from /Resources to a List<BitmapImage> (c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, list, bitmapimage

As a selfteaching project I am building a memory game as a WPF app.

The question: is there an efficient way of adding all the image files from Resources dirrectory to a `List<BitmapImage>` so that I can easiely create a grid of x amount of images?

The ideal for me would have been to store all those images once in a list and cycle through the list in order to set the `(Image)pictureBox.Source = myImageList[i]`

The constrains here are that the `myImage.BeginInit()` method can only be called once, and on top of that it is not possible to override an instance of a BitmapImage. (by "cannot override" I mean that I cannot change the picture held by the BitmapImage once it has been set.

Conclusion: I have a lot of pictures in my resource folder. Is there a better way than the following piece of code to save all my images from that folder in a list. (since this method requires me to create an instance of a BitmapImage for each resource I want to add to the list. It feels inefficient)

```
            BitmapImage myImage0 = new BitmapImage();

            myImage0.BeginInit();
            myImage0.UriSource = new Uri(@"/resources/ukflag.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
            pictureBox.Source = myImage0;
            myImage0.EndInit();
            myImageList.Add(myImage0);
```

Comment: Shorter: `myImageList.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("/resources/ukflag.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));`

Comment: If this is not realistic I would also like to know

Comment: The image files should actually be assembly resources, i.e. their Build Action should be set to Resource. You would load them from Resource File Pack URIs like `myImageList.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/ukflag.jpg")));`

Comment: @Clemens thanks I will try your shorter version. I will change the Build action of all resources if necessary. But I will still have to copy this line for each picture I am trying to add, I was trying to find out a workarround for that.

Comment: As an alternative, iterate over all `*.jpg` files in a directory and create a BitmapImage from each.

Comment: Could you not use something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639688/how-to-get-a-list-of-xaml-resources-defined-in-an-assembly to get the list of resources? You could filter it as needed with Where(...)

Comment: @StayOnTarget That would require that there are BitmapImage resources in some ResourceDictionary (i.e. a XAML file), which is not what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I found a way.
here is the code that worked for me (after setting build action of the pictures to resource)

```
ResourceSet resourceSet = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
        {
            string resourceKey = entry.Key.ToString();
            
            myImageList.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/" + resourceKey + ".jpg")));
        }
```